# How to make sharepoint site view by all

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/default.aspx

the above link is the sharepoint 2010  site of blog template . Can anyone help me how to do as same for posting my blogs . How to make the site to view for all without authentication.

Regards,

Zakeer

Answer (score 3):

To make a site collection able to be viewed by anyone you have to enable Anonymous acces. See [this link](http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-9-turn-on-anonymous.html) for a guide from Randy Drisgill.

Basically you do the following steps:

1. From the web application settings in CA, you edit the authentication provider for the web application hosting you blog. In this settings you enable anonymous acces.
2. Next you go to the site settings -> Site permissions of the blog, here you can click the "Anonymous acces" button on the ribbon, from there set anonymous acces for the entire web site.